# Java collections vs manual loops - Coding challenges/interview best practices

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, collections

For coding challenges/interview as well as optimization, is it good to use collections at all? For example, check the palindrome running time for below program

```
    import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();

        if(isPalindrome(str)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }

        if(isPalindromeUsingSet(str)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }

    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long duration;
        for (int i=0;i<str.length()/2;i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() -1 -i)) {
                duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime; 
                System.out.println("isPalindrome - " + duration);
                return false;
            } 
        }
        duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime; 
        System.out.println("isPalindrome - " + duration);

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindromeUsingSet(String str) {
    final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    final long duration;
    Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i=0;i<str.length()/2;i++) {
        if(charSet.add(str.charAt(i)) == false) {
            duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime; 
            System.out.println("isPalindromeUsingSet - " + duration);
            return false;
        } else {
            charSet.remove(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime; 
    System.out.println("isPalindromeUsingSet - " + duration);
    return true;
}

}
```

Running Time as calculated is shown below.

```
AMANAPLANACANALPANAMA
isPalindrome - 7788
YES
isPalindromeUsingSet - 745473
YES
```

My couple of questions are:

1. So java collections are mostly safe and versatile in various CRUD
   operations, why not use them?
2. For coding better optimized solutions, should I look for one loop
   execution, use a lot of O(1) data structures?

My approach in learning optmization code:

1. For each coding problem, solve my crude way of java and data
   structures.
2. Go and study the best solution later, calculate time and complexity and adapt in my solutions gradually.

**Background**:
I've been coding java for couple of years.  Now learning coding for puzzles, algorithms and time complexity for acing bigger interviews!

Any good direction is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand your second approach. The second function looks like not doing the same job as the first!

Comment: Your second function is wrong - it returns true for AABB. Also, you should read up on proper benchmarking, because what you did there would not give you meaningful measurements for multiple reasons (the input size is too small, it doesn't take long enough and you're measuring time over a single iteration). Also, the answer to this is roughly "consider the time and space complexity of any given approach (along with constant factors), not whether it uses a Java collection or not".

Comment: Don't use Set. An element is added to the Set only if it does not already exist in the Set

Comment: Now I get it, all the inputs were having repeating characters, I wont be using set, I see it can be used to find if duplicate character exists!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `HashSet.add` implementation:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Internally, `HashSet` uses a `HashMap`.

Now, let's take a look at the `HashMap.put` method implementation:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

We can notice that puting a registry into the map it's a "hard task", computationally speaking. There is a:

- hash algorithm
- `for` loop
- add entry method execution
- and so on...

So, if execution time it's a concern in your scenario, manual loops it's a better choice than Java Collections.

Now, in terms of readability and maintainability, Collections is the best choice.

Comment: I agree upon the readability and maintainability, these days all the systems are super fast. Since I'm rooted to use java collections which is a bit expensive in memory. Just making a switch to use low level loops for optimization in coding interviews.

Answer (score 1):

Closed after understanding the comparison was wrong with two functions.

Comment: Right. You didn't compare the speed of a `Set` against something else, but rather against doing nothing. So the `Set` had to lose. ;)